# linear inequalities using LP solutions not from simplex

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, simplex

I am trying to solve a set of inequalities using linear programming (LP) with objective function set as a constant.
Usually this set of inequalities would have many solutions, all of them in the feasible region.

However, the library I am using (python pulp) gives solutions from the simplex, which sometimes make my variables vanish (sets some of the variables to zero).
Since my objective function is constant, I would like to receive a random solution from the feasible region, and not just from the simplex.
How can I do that?

Is there any constraint to ensure that I get a solution from the internal feasible region - not just simplex? (Can pulp can do it? Can any other python lib?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which solver are hooked to Pulp, but a first try would be running an interior-point based algorithm. This will give you a solution in the interior of the feasible set. Actually you won't get a random solution, unless the algorithm implementation is not completely deterministic. To overcome this, why not just randomly generate a random set of costs for the variables?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "first try would be running an interior-point based algorithm"? which one? The objective function is constant, so I can't generate random set of costs.

Comment: Any linear solver implementing an interior-point algorithm will do. Your objective function is constant just because it is a feasibility problem. Since any solution is good for you, you can define a linear objective function as you please.

Answer (score -1):

See "A version of the simplex method for solving linear
systems of inequalities and linear programming
problems" Evald Übi

Comment: You are directing us to an article. Are you willing to summarize the relevant points here, on this site? You may click "Edit" to improve your answer. Welcome to Math Stack.